# How to get metadata of hive tables, columns, views, constraint keys and comment columns?

Tags: hadoop, hive

Please help me out how get metadata of hive tables, columns, views, constraint keys and comment columns.

Comment: I have found simple queries like desc table_name;show databses. But I need with system tables and columns ,views to get metedata.

Comment: This should all be available in the Hive metastore.  Details will depend on your implentation.

Comment: please give me more clear idea ...

Answer (score 8):

if you have Hue available you can go to Metastore Tables from the top menu Data Browsers. There you can find metadata for all schemas available for you.
From Hive you can try:
`USE DB_NAME;`
`DESCRIBE FORMATTED TABLE_NAME;`
or
`DESCRIBE EXTENDED TABLE_NAME;`

Answer (score 3):

It can be viewed by this simple query `describe formatted table_name`

Comment: we have used this query in oracle   SELECT table_Name from USER_TABLES.           System tables we used for oracle same thing need to apply HIVE to get columns using system tables. Please help me in that.

Answer (score 1):

Below are some metadata tables from the RDBMS hive metastore.

**TBLS** - Tables, external tables & views Metadata

**DBS** - Database metadata

**PARTITIONS** - Table partition metadata

**KEY_CONSTRAINTS** - Table constraints metadata

For Column related metadata you need to join multiple tables like **COLUMNS_V2**, **SDS**, **TBLS** & **DBS**

Answer (score 0):

Use Hcatlog.

Maven dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hive.hcatalog</groupId>
        <artifactId>hive-webhcat-java-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Sample code:

```
HiveConf hcatConf = new HiveConf();

hcatConf.setVar(HiveConf.ConfVars.METASTOREURIS, connectionUri);
hcatConf.set("hive.metastore.local", "false");

HCatClient client = null;
HCatTable hTable = null;

try {
    client = HCatClient.create(hcatConf);
    hTable = client.getTable(databaseName, tableName);
    System.out.println(hTable.getLocation());
    System.out.println(hTable.getInputFileFormat());
    System.out.println(hTable.getOutputFileFormat());
    // other properties
} catch (HCatException hCatEx) {
    LOG.error("Not able to connect to hive. Caused By;", hCatEx);
}
```

Check available methods of [**HCatTable**](https://hive.apache.org/javadocs/r0.13.1/api/hcatalog/webhcat/java-client/org/apache/hcatalog/api/HCatTable.html).

Comment: we have used this query in oracle SELECT table_Name from USER_TABLES. System tables we used for oracle same thing need to apply HIVE to get columns using system tables.

Answer (score 0):

If you access to hive metastore(rdbm systems like mysql, postgresql etc), you will be able to access complete information. Contact your cluster admin who has configured the hive metastore if you do not have the access.