# Querying HIVE Metadata

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql, hadoop2, hortonworks-data-platform

I need to query the following table and view information from my Apache HIVE cluster:

Each row needs to contain the following:

TABLE SCHEMA

TABLE NAME

TABLE DESCRIPTION

COLUMN NAME

COLUMN DATA TYPE

COLUMN LENGTH

COLUMN PRECISION

COLUMN SCALE

NULL OR NOT NULL

PRIMARY KEY INDICATOR

This can be easily queried from most RDBMS (metadata tables/views), but I am struggling to find much information about the equivalent metadata tables/views in HIVE.

Please help :)

Comment: a possibel duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40302116/how-to-get-metadata-of-hive-tables-columns-views-constraint-keys-and-comment

Answer (score 7):

This information is available from the Hive metastore. The below example query is for a MySQL-backed metastore (Hive version 1.2).

```
SELECT 
DBS.NAME AS TABLE_SCHEMA,
TBLS.TBL_NAME AS TABLE_NAME,
TBL_COMMENTS.TBL_COMMENT AS TABLE_DESCRIPTION,
COLUMNS_V2.COLUMN_NAME AS COLUMN_NAME,
COLUMNS_V2.TYPE_NAME AS COLUMN_DATA_TYPE_DETAILS
FROM DBS
JOIN TBLS ON DBS.DB_ID = TBLS.DB_ID
JOIN SDS ON TBLS.SD_ID = SDS.SD_ID
JOIN COLUMNS_V2 ON COLUMNS_V2.CD_ID = SDS.CD_ID
JOIN 
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT TBL_ID, TBL_COMMENT 
        FROM 
        (
            SELECT TBLS.TBL_ID TBL_ID, TABLE_PARAMS.PARAM_KEY, TABLE_PARAMS.PARAM_VALUE, CASE WHEN TABLE_PARAMS.PARAM_KEY = 'comment' THEN TABLE_PARAMS.PARAM_VALUE ELSE '' END TBL_COMMENT
            FROM TBLS JOIN TABLE_PARAMS
            ON TBLS.TBL_ID = TABLE_PARAMS.TBL_ID
        ) TBL_COMMENTS_INTERNAL
    ) TBL_COMMENTS 
ON TBLS.TBL_ID = TBL_COMMENTS.TBL_ID;
```

**Sample output:**

```
+--------------+----------------------+-----------------------+-------------------+------------------------------+
| TABLE_SCHEMA | TABLE_NAME           | TABLE_DESCRIPTION     | COLUMN_NAME       | COLUMN_DATA_TYPE_DETAILS     |
+--------------+----------------------+-----------------------+-------------------+------------------------------+
| default      | temp003              | This is temp003 table | col1              | string                       |
| default      | temp003              | This is temp003 table | col2              | array<string>                |
| default      | temp003              | This is temp003 table | col3              | array<string>                |
| default      | temp003              | This is temp003 table | col4              | int                          |
| default      | temp003              | This is temp003 table | col5              | decimal(10,2)                |
| default      | temp004              |                       | col11             | string                       |
| default      | temp004              |                       | col21             | array<string>                |
| default      | temp004              |                       | col31             | array<string>                |
| default      | temp004              |                       | col41             | int                          |
| default      | temp004              |                       | col51             | decimal(10,2)                |
+--------------+----------------------+-----------------------+-------------------+------------------------------+
```

**Metastore tables referred in query:**

```
DBS: Details of databases/schemas.
TBLS: Details of tables.
COLUMNS_V2: Details about columns.
SDS: Details about storage.
TABLE_PARAMS: Details about table parameters (key-value pairs)
```